# Coupling differential line to a single ended daq

Tags: signal-integrity

Sorry for the primitive drawing but it was for clarity of the question:

[image]

If a differential balanced signal will be conveyed to a single ended inputs of a DAQ, what would be the proper connection?

Following the above illustration, the signal comes from a balanced driver where A and B are inverted. S is the shield of the two core cable. The signal is coupled through XLR. But on the receiver end we only have a single ended receiver or DAQ. In this case how should be the proper coupling there?

A to X is for sure. The rest is not so clear:

B to Y and S floats? Or S to Y and B floats?

Comment: Is the common mode voltage of the differential signal always within the range of the amplifier's power supplies? And what is the frequency range of the signal? Does it include DC or is it purely AC?

Comment: I think S the shield is connected to the differential transmitter’s analog ground. I guess that is also connected to the power supply ground. Speaking more about audio signal. Freq is lower than 20kHz.

Comment: Knowing the shield voltage doesn't tell you the differential signal's common mode voltage. What is the source of the differential signal? (schematic if possible)

Comment: Please edit the question to include this important information. The question should be understandable and answerable without reading comments.

Comment: And what is "XLR"?

Comment: This is a generic question there is no circuit or schematics. The motivation came after this video https://youtu.be/dHnqZMUPqbc There are many disagreements under the comments about what he says.

Comment: There is no proper connection that would avoid common mode noise pickup without using an isolation transformer (balun).